# Why to use #newBuilder() function in Builder Pattern? Is it mandatory?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using the Builder Pattern since time ago, but these days one of my collegues reach me with a question to which I never thought about, and is about the #newBuilder() function in the Builder Pattern.

I've seen in several forums, tutorials, and even APIs, that when using the Builder Pattern, a structure like this is usually used:

```
Car car1 = new CarBuilder().newBuilder().twoDoors().fourWheels().build();
```

Usually, inside of the #newBuilder() function, there is a code like this:

```
public static CarBuilder newBuilder(){
  return new CarBuilder();
}
```

The question is, why should be needed a #newBuilder() function in the Builder class? Is it a good practice to have it, or is needed only when overloading is applied? I mean, just in the cases where I need to overload the #newBuilder() having 2 or 3 different #newBuilder() functions with different parameters.

What if I will have only one #newBuilder() function in the Builder class? Should I implement it, or can I avoid it and do something like:

```
Car car1 = new CarBuilder().twoDoors().fourWheels().build();
```

The question of my colleague was: If I implement the #newBuilder() function, am I falling in redundancy with the first example if I will only have one #newBuilder() function in my Builder class?

What you think about this? Should I remove it or it is justified to have the #newBuilder() function despite of I have only one implementation of it without overloading?

Thanks!

Comment: If `newBuilder()` is static, then it is certainly _not_ the case that `new CarBuilder().newBuilder()` is typically used. It would be `CarBuilder.newBuilder()...`

Comment: Yes, you have been doing it wrong. Also, if you have a factory method, it is recommended to make the constructor private.

Comment: I usually create the builder in a static function on the actual class that will be built. Like `Car.builder()`. This is both shorter and conveys a bit more meaning I think.

Comment: There are multiple styles, and what you choose is more or less a matter of taste / opinion. One general principle to remember: don't do things without understanding why (for example just because it's part of a formula) - always think about what the pros and cons are of a particular approach.

Comment: @RealSkeptic so you think that the second approach, without the #newBuilder() function, is more appropiate in my case? I only have one #newBuilder() function in my Builder class, with no overloading

Comment: @marstran you're saying that instead of calling the CarBuilder class to create the intance of the Car, you call the CarBuilder inside the Car class? Then, if you need to have different instances of the Car with different approches (one with two doors and other with three for example) how you handle that if you don't call the builder directly? Just trying to understand you're point =)

Comment: @Jesper totally agree with you! But as I always see in the tutorials the #newBuilder() function, without an explanation like the one I'm looking for, I just assumed that is part of it. =(

Comment: @daniellozano Yeah, if the builder returns different types based on the input, then I would probably make the builder-function as a static function on the builder-class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this:

> ```java
> Car car1 = new CarBuilder().newBuilder().twoDoors().fourWheels().build();
> ```

Is definitely redundant, but not because the `newBuilder()` method exists. The problem is your code is essentially this:

```java
CarBuilder builder1 = new CarBuilder();
CarBuilder builder2 = builder1.newBuilder();
Car car1 = builder2.twoDoors().fourWheels().build();
```

In other words, you're creating **two instances** of `CarBuilder`. Also, you're calling a `static` method on an instance reference, which is frowned upon. With your current setup, your code should be either:

```java
Car car1 = new CarBuilder().twoDoors().fourWheels().build();
```

OR:

```java
Car car1 = CarBuilder.newBuilder().twoDoors().fourWheels().build();
```

Which style you choose is up to you. However, if you choose to use the second approach (the static factory method `newBuilder()`), then typically the builder's constructor is made `private`, or at least package-private, so that `new CarBuilder()` cannot be used by external code.

So, I would say "no", having `newBuilder()` is not redundant in and of itself, as long as you use it correctly. It's simply an *alternative* way of creating a builder instance without calling the constructor directly. Note using the static factory method approach may aid in readability, because you can name the method something more descriptive. You may not see that advantage unless you have a significant number of different factory methods with different semantics, however.

---

Another thing to consider is where to place the `newBuilder()` static method. If `CarBuilder` and `Car` are extremely coupled, then many developers will put the static method in the `Car` class instead of the `CarBuilder` class (if not just nest the latter in the former).

For example:

```java
package sample;

public final class Car {

  public static CarBuilder newBuilder() {
    return new CarBuilder();
  }

  private final int numberOfDoors;
  private final int numberOfWheels;

  Car(CarBuilder builder) {
    this.numberOfDoors = builder.numberOfDoors;
    this.numberOfWheels = builder.numberOfWheels;
  }

  // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

```java
package sample;

public final class CarBuilder {

  private int numberOfDoors; // should initialize to sensible default
  private int numberOfWheels; // should initialize to sensible default

  CarBuilder() {}

  public CarBuilder twoDoors() {
    numberOfDoors = 2;
    return this;
  }

  public CarBuilder fourWheels() {
    numberOfWheels = 4;
    return this;
  }

  public Car build() {
    return new Car(this);
  }
}
```

Which could then be used like so:

```java
Car car1 = Car.newBuilder().twoDoors().fourWheels().build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get your point and I can understand the correct ways to use the #newBuilder() function with this pattern. Much appreciated! Voted as solution for me